# cassandra.input.split.size is not reflecting in DSE3.2.4 Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, hive, datastax-enterprise

I am processing Cassandra tables using Hive in DSE3.2.4.
Irrespective of the table size it is running 513 mappers for each job.
I tried to change

```
cassandra.input.split.size 65536
mapred.min.split.size 1000000
```

these are reflecting in Job.xml but no luck,

tring changing `mapred.map.tasks to 4` is not reflecting in Job.xml, I know this won't reflect but just gave a try

I still don't understand why this fancy Number 513?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

513 = 256 vnodes splits * 2 + 1

This makes me guess you have a 2 node cluster.  The number of splits is dependent on two things. The number of token ranges in the cluster and the number of partitions in those ranges. Currently every vnodes range is made into at least one split which is why vnodes are not recommended for use with analytics clusters.

Comment: what should I do now?
Do u have any documentation where they explain about this?
This is too bad even If query for 10row table now it will take splits from n*2+1 
Then what is the use of cassandra.input.split.size, page size all those parameters?
Can I try changing any Input format?

Comment: Well either you don't use vnodes (but you will still have a minimum of one split per node) or you do map reduce on more than 10 rows. Map reduce is meant for 100s of thousands rows and bulk operations.

Comment: Then taking Input from Cassandra through PIG or Hive will run constant MAPS which depends on no.of token range or No.of Vnodes?
and changing input format class also don't work?
I am trying to change InputFormat class to CqlPagingInputFormat
then only high record table is recommended to run analytics in DSE?

Comment: If I disable Vnodes and again restart by generating tokens in my 2 node cluster. Will it take 2Maps or it takes depending on Table size?

Comment: It's always depending on table size but there is a *minimum*. That minimum is number of token ranges in the cluster. If your table had 10M rows and a split size of 20k you would get 5000 splits.

Comment: then take this case
If I have a 6.4M rows table and split size is 64k 
and 2nodes with 256Vnodes I will get max(513,100) 513 maps running
and same 2 nodes with normal installation will get max(2,100) 100 maps running?

Comment: My table is now with 300K rows and my cassandra.input.split.size=100 and I have 2 nodes with num_tokens=256
now I should get max(513,3000)=3000 splits but still I can see only 513 mappers running